# How can I start mysql on system start?

Tags: mac, boot, mysql

Every time I start my system. I have to run a command

```
 sudo /usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64/support-files/mysql.server start
```

to start mysql. How can I start it automatically on login (System start)?

Comment: fyi, login and system start are _not_ the same thing

Comment: Please accept my answer if it worked for you or comment on it so I or others have the opportunity to solve your problem. This question was just bumped to the front page, since the system considers it unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you install MySQL?

There are official installer packages for OS X, that have an [installer for a startup item](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/macosx-installation-startupitem.html) and a [preference pane](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/macosx-installation-prefpane.html) for System Preferences to easily toggle auto-start of MySQL.

Comment: Didnt worked for me..

Comment: @Mohit That's why I asked how you installed it. There are multiple ways to do this, and this answer works for one of them.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know how you installed MySQL, but if you have a MySQL symlink in `/etc/init.d` then you can run `update-rc.d` as follows which will add mysql to your list of apps which are run at system start-up.

```
sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults
```

For info on update-rc.d use:

```
man update-rc.d
```

Comment: -1, the user is on OS X, there's no such thing as `update-rc.d`.